# Change AS3 Component Font

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, components, flash-cs4

I want to change font name, font size and character embedding properties of a component (Combobox in my case) through Flash IDE (not in action script).
Is there an option to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It looks that there is no way to skin font of default flash components. I ended up writing my own.

Comment: what does this have to do with programming?

Comment: @negative... yeah, I'm aware of that faq... but it seems to support my implied assertion that your question doesn't belong here.  Why not ask a question about a cake recipe while you're at it? If you don't want a coding solution to your problem, then you should ask Flash IDE questions at Adobe's Flash site, no?

Comment: @MaksimVi. Was your custom component able to display the font in Live Preview? I can get mine to work when running the movie itself, but Live Preview just appears blank. You're one of two other people out there I've found who tried doing this, and the only person posting a success story.

Answer (score 4):

No, you need to use ActionScript to do that.  Here is how I do it:

```
package com.twoa.ui.base.controls {
    import fl.controls.ComboBox;
    import fl.controls.List;
    import flash.text.Font;
    import flash.text.TextFormat;

    public class MyComboBox extends ComboBox {

        private var textFormat:TextFormat;
        private var textFormat2:TextFormat;

        public function MyComboBox() {
            super();
            forceStyle();
        }

        public function forceStyle() {

            var f:Font = new Interface();

            var textFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat()
            textFormat.size = 8;
            textFormat.color = 0xffffff;
            textFormat.font = f.fontName

            var textFormat2:TextFormat = new TextFormat()
            textFormat2.size = 8;
            textFormat2.color = 0xffffff;
            textFormat2.font = f.fontName

            dropdown.setRendererStyle("embedFonts", true);
            dropdown.setRendererStyle("textFormat", textFormat);

            textField.setStyle("embedFonts", true);
            textField.setStyle("textFormat", textFormat2);

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: well, the thing is that I am using default comboBox component and do quite a lot of skinning in IDE (I would have to write really lots of code in action script for that). I believe that using my own class won't allow me to change its look through Flash IDE.